# Getting MongoDb schema right

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Looking for a good way to store data for my planned app.

Each of my members can have "many" users and each user can have potentially "squillions" of items.

As for queries I will need to:

- ADD new items
- GET all users by member.
- GET all items by user. There will be no need to access a specific item.
- GET all items by member.

I'm thinking of de-normalizing and duplicating data - long writes, quick reads but if anyone has any suggestions on this matter I would love to hear them.

Comment: Can a user be owned by more than one member?

Comment: No, a member has their own set of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've said about the data and application queries, I would advise a schema where the `member` documents contain a `users` array which contains `user` subdocuments. *However, not knowing how big these `user` documents can get or how "many" a single `member` will have, I can't be sure that this will not cause the `member` document to grow too large.*

Both `member` and `user` have an ID.

Then, in a separate `item` collection, each `item` document has `member_id` and `user_id` fields. There is an index of `{ member_id: 1, user_id: 1 }` on this `item` collection.

With this setup:

### ADD new items

```
db.items.insert({user_id: <user_id>, member_id: <member_id>, weight: 4});
```

### GET all users by member

```
db.member.find({_id: <member_id>}, {users: 1});
```

### GET all items by user

```
db.items.find({member_id: <member_id>, user_id: <user_id>})
```

### GET all items by member

```
db.items.find({member_id: <member_id>})
```

The important thing to remember for this setup is that when searching for items by user you **must** specify `member_id` as well or it will not use the index. The index I suggested (`{ member_id: 1, user_id: 1 }`) can be used to help queries that only use `member_id`, but it cannot be used to help queries that only use `user_id`. The order matters with an index.

If it makes sense to shard the `items` collection at some point, consider using the `member_id` as a shard key.